# Regex matching too many results

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract the part in the href only once. However I also need to specify that it must match only hrefs where the following text is: `Launch Information Processing Workflow`,

```
<a class="wcmListViewLink" target="_blank" href="getContent?objectStoreName=Nice&vsId=%7BE6B85994-9B93-4A3C-878A-C7BBBA39BAD8%7D&objectType=document&folderId=%7BB51627F8-D74C-4607-ADD7-AC9C125D67F9%7D">Launch Information Processing Workflow</a>
```

The following reged worked:

```
href="(.+?)%7D"
```

How can I make it more specific and require the `Launch Information Processing Workflow` text piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add `.*` to match any characters between `"` and `>Launch`.
   (**E.g**: `href="link" class="btn">Launch`)

This one should works :

```
/href="(.+?)\".*?>Launch/
```

You can check it here : https://regex101.com/r/rN0tI5/2

Answer (score 0):

[It is not very recommended to parse HTML using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider using [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) configured as follows:

- Reference Name: any reasonable variable name
- XPath Expression: `//a[text()='Launch Information Processing Workflow']/@href`
- Check `Use Tidy` box just in case of response is not XHTML-compliant